# How to get two values from two seperate lists to print (python)

Tags: python, list, zip

Here’s my problem, I have two different lists, list `a` which contains the name of people and list `b` which contains their phone numbers:

```
a = ["peter", "bob", "john", "jack"]
b = ["8954 3434", "8999 4432", "8976 5443", "8990 3331"]
```

What I need to do is prompt users for a input which will be a name from list `a` and then python should automatically print out the phone number for that person from list `b`.

I came across a code that seems pretty interesting:

```
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    print x, y
```

This pretty much prints every single name and the corresponding phone number next to it which is basically what I need, however rather than every name from list a appearing, what I need is for the user to be able to enter a single name and for that names phone number to show up.

Just to clarify, using the above code gives me the output:

```
peter 8954 3434
bob 8999 4432
john 8976 5443
jack 8990 3331
```

While what I want is for the user to be able to enter a name e.g "peter" which should give the output:

```
peter 8954 3434
```

Is there a way to edit that above code to get things to work properly? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hmm I was told "To loop through two or more sequences at the same time, the entries can be paired with the zip() function" so I assumed a zip function was the way to go. Index seems to work fine so I guess theres no issue, but is there really no way to get this to work using zip() just so that I have two different methods for this?

Comment: This should be tagged "Homework"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic way to solve this:

```
who = raw_input("Give a name")
for name, number in zip(a, b): 
    if name == who:
        print name, number
```

I hope it's homework.

Comment: @RikeshPadhiar: Compare this to the basic `for ... zip()` example in your question -- you couldn't figure out the `if` by yourself?

Answer (score 4):

Put your data in a dictionary:

```
>>> a = ["peter", "bob", "john", "jack"]
>>> b = ["8954 3434", "8999 4432", "8976 5443", "8990 3331"]
>>> phone_numbers = dict(zip(a,b))
```

Then you can get someone's phone number from their name:

```
>>> phone_numbers['john']
'8976 5443'
```

If you want to do this only using lists, you can use `index` but note that this will have poor performance:

```
b[a.index('john')]
'8976 5443'
```

Comment: Wouldn't this have problem if two people have the same name?

Comment: Like I said above, I have to use a list for this problem

Comment: Thanks index works, but if possible I'd like to use the zip() function

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like

```
print b[a.index("bob")]
```

?

Comment: Thanks it works, but if possible I'd like to use the zip() function

Comment: @RikeshPadhiar doesn't make much sense here but this should work using zip. 
    print [y for x,y in zip(a,b) if x=='peter']

Answer (score 1):

> I have to use a list for this problem

If you can't use `phone = dict(zip(a,b)).get("peter")` then using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
phones = [phone for name, phone in zip(a,b) if name == "peter"]
```

It returns a list of `"peter"`'s phone numbers. It allows you to have several entries with the same name. If lists are large then it is much slower then the `dict` approach ([`O(1)` vs. `O(N)`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=573138)).

If you need only one number then using [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next):

```
phone = next((phone for name, phone in zip(a,b) if name == "peter"), None)
```

It returns the first match from the list. `phone` is `None` if there is no such name in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Put them into a dictionary:

```
people = dict(zip(a, b))
```

Then just look names up:

```
name = "john"
print("%s's number is %s" % (input, people[name]))
```

Comment: The problem is I have to use a list, which is why this is so tricky. xD

Comment: This question came up in a past exam so I have to know how to do it just in case it turns up again

Comment: @RikeshPadhiar: It's not tricky at all, but stupidly simple.  Just get the index with `list.index()` and use this to get the matching value.  See Mark Byers answer.

Comment: Thanks index works, but if possible I'd like to use the zip() function

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary of the zipped lists:

```
names = ["peter", "bob", "john", "jack"]
phones = ["8954 3434", "8999 4432", "8976 5443", "8990 3331"]
phones_by_name = dict(zip(names, phones))
print "bob", phones_by_name["bob"]
print "jack", phones_by_name["jack"]
```

gives:

```
bob 8999 4432
jack 8990 3331
```

Comment: is there no way to get that to work but for lists instead of dict?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use an `if` statement?

```
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    if x == name_input:
        print x, y
```

or I guess in the context of your code

```
for name, phone in zip(names_list, phone_list):
    if name == name_input:
        print name, phone
```

But you should tell your teacher to use `dict`